# I don't want the Apply option

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to MYSQL Workbench. When we change the table values in the grid, we need to press the `apply button`.
Is there a way we can disable that option i.e. when we change the values in the grid, the changes gets reflected immediately?

Answer (score 0):

No. The changes must be sent to the server and executing an update query on each cell edit action can lead to a lot of traffic.